# Open a file in the default editor from the browser and navigate to the line number

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, browser

If you have used `create-react-app`, you may have noticed that when an error occurs, this application displays a page with this very error from the console.

[image]

If you click on this error, the default editor will be opened and the cursor will move to the line where the error occurred.

How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

you can open vscode using this url **vscode://filepath**